# Strategy for avoiding file upload naming conflicts

Tags: ruby-on-rails, web-applications, concurrency, amazon-s3

I have a webapp in Rails which as an AJAX file upload feature. Files are uploaded to a remote server (AWS S3). My current strategy is to upload the files in a `temp/` directory (with their original name) until the user submits the form, and then rename them to their definitive name.

But the problem is that if multiple users try to upload two files with the same names at the same time, then one is gonna override the other.

The strategy I was thinking of to solve this was to generate random SHA1 when the upload page is loaded, store them in a table locally to make sure they're unique, and remove them when the temp file is renamed.

Do you see problems with this approach?

What's a good strategy to solve this problem?

Comment: Why the SHA1 and not just a GUID or `mktempfile` generator? A reason to use SHA1 over the contents would be if is expected that duplicate resources are added *and* it is used as a method of duplicate control *and* resources are considered immutable once uploaded. However, if that is not the case .. (then imagine where two people upload two empty file at the same time).

Answer (score 0):

One problem is, if they navigate away from the page without uploading anything, their hash will stay in the database, and eventually make a mess.  I would avoid storing anything this temporary in the database.

Rather than try to come up with your own way to name temporary files, why not use the ruby [tempfile library](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html), which will do it for you?

---

Originally, I thought you were uploading the files to the ruby server, and uploading them to s3 yourself.  Tempfiles won't help if users are uploading files directly.  If you just want unique names for your temp files, a UUID generator might work for you.  There is a [Ruby UUID generator gem](https://github.com/assaf/uuid/) which is designed to not produce duplicates, even in a distributed setting.  If you name your files with these, you shouldn't need to store anything in the database.

Comment: This cleanup needs to be handled in all cases anyway (even for temporary files alone), and is a trivial maintenance job.

Comment: The problem is that the files are not uploaded to my local server, but to AWS S3, so I don't have control over it. I already have a cronjob for cleaning up temp files that have more than 24 hours, I could easily remove old entries from the DB at the same time.

Comment: Do your users have to be logged in to upload files, or can anyone upload?